# Evaluate the following integral

Tags: integration

I am trying to evaluate $$\int_{0}^{a} \frac{dx}{x+\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}$$ but I don't think I am doing the right thing.

My attempt:

Use the identity that $$\int_0^a f(x)dx=\int_0^a f(a-x)dx$$ and I got $$\int_{0}^{a}\frac{dx}{(a-x)+\sqrt{x^{2}-2ax}}dx$$ but this doesn't seem to help.

Comment: $(x+\sqrt{x^2-a^2})\cdot (x-\sqrt{x^2-a^2}) = \dots$

Comment: Are you sure that it's $\sqrt{x^2-a^2}$?

Comment: If you regard it as a complex function, yes.  If you regard it as a real function, then the integrand (and thus the integral) is undefined.  Of course that's only for positive values of a; for negative a there is no problem here.

Comment: $$x^2-a^2\ge 0\iff x^2\ge a^2\iff |x|\ge|a|\implies$$ also if $\,a<0\,$ we still have that the square root in the denominator isn't defined in the reals and this is thus either an undefined integral (real analysis) or a complex one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $a^2<x^2$ for real $a,x $, note that $\displaystyle \int_{0}^a \frac{dx}{x+\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}=\displaystyle \frac{1}{a^2}\int_{0}^a (x-\sqrt{x^2-a^2})dx$. Split the integral and try to find out $\displaystyle \int_{0}^a \sqrt{x^2-a^2}$ using integration by parts.

Comment: $$x^2\ge a^2\iff |x|\ge |a|\implies $$the function's undefined *as a real function* in the interval $\,[0,a]\,$ , no matter whether $\,a<0\,$ or $\,a>0\,$

Comment: @DonAntonio, does that mean that I have made a mistake? Should I delete or modify my answer? I was quite hasty to write down what I did.Edit: I made it community wiki. Please feel free to correct my mistakes.

Comment: I really don't know what to do in this case: the integrand function is not defined, as areal function, in the integration interval...that integral, imo, doesn't even exist.